# How can I fold paper into 3 x 4 grid? Or prove that it can't be done?

Tags: geometry

I am trying to fold paper so that it looks like 3 x 4 grid of 12 rectangles of equal size.

Like this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3+x+4

Its easy to get 4 rectangles. Just fold twice. But how to get 3?

Comment: The Pythagoras theorem may help $3^2+4^2=5^2$ is the relationship b/w sides of a right triangle.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736346/how-can-a-piece-of-a4-paper-be-folded-in-exactly-three-equal-parts

This would help you divide it into 3 parts

Comment: This question was asked before that question so that one is duplicate of this one :D lol

Comment: This question is 11 months older

Answer (score 4):

Let the paper be $[0,a]\times[0,b]$
By halving you find $(\frac a2,0)$, make a crease to find the line through $(\frac a2,0)$ and $(0,b)$. This intersects the diagonal at $(\frac a3,\frac b3)$.

Answer (score 2):

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8d/Haga_theorem_1.svg

If your piece of paper is a square ABCD of side length 1, then from the diagram, if AP=1/2, then QC=1/3.

Answer (score 2):

(Stealing from Hagen von Eitzen's answer and Ross Millikan diagram at [How can a piece of A4 paper be folded in exactly three equal parts?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736346/can-a-piece-of-a4-paper-be-folded-in-exactly-three-equal-parts))

[image: Graphical representation of the folds]

1. Fold the paper into four equal horizontal strips with two folds
2. Fold a diagonal across the top three horizontal strips
3. Fold vertical strips at the two points where the diagonal crosses the horizontal strips.